# If $\frac{(x+1+i)^n -(x+1-i)^n}{2i}=k$ and $\cot(Q)=x+1$ prove $k=\csc^n(Q)\cdot\sin(nQ)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $$\frac{(x+1+i)^n -(x+1-i)^n}{2i}=k$$ and $$\cot(Q)=x+1$$ prove that $$k=\csc^n(Q)\cdot\sin(nQ)$$
replacing value of $\cot{Q}$
$$\frac{(\cot(Q)+i)^n -(\cot(Q)-i)^n}{2i}$$
and taking out $\sqrt{\cot^2(Q)+1}$ as common
$$\frac{\csc^n(Q)(\cos(Q)+i/\csc(Q))^n -\csc^n(Q)(\cot(Q)-i/\csc(Q))^n}{2i}$$
finally it becomes 
$$\frac{\csc^n(Q)(2i/\csc(Q))^n}{2i}$$
applying de-moivre's theorem it becomes
$$k=\csc^n(Q).\sin(nQ).(2i)^{n-1}$$
where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get the line after "finally it becomes"?  Looks like you said
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)^n$$
which of course is not true.

Try this: write
$$x+1+i=re^{i\theta}\ .$$
Then
$$\cot\theta=x+1\ ,\quad r=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}=\csc\theta$$
and your expression is
$${\rm Im}\bigl((x+1+i)^n\bigr)={\rm Im}\bigl(r^ne^{ni\theta}\bigr)=\csc^n\theta\sin n\theta\ .$$

---

Note that since ${\rm Im}(x+1+i)>0$ we have $\csc\theta>0$, otherwise we would have to write $r=|\csc\theta|$.